Problem with column size in list web part - New list view layout
Since a few weeks, we have in SharePoint Online the new (modern) view in a list.
I know, if you want to display a column wider or narrower, you can change this column width and save the view.
The problem is, when you use this view in a web part on a page, it does not respect the set width.

A normal user will see it in a minimum width.

The person who modified the view temporarily sees the correct width. After a while, he also sees the column in a minimum width.

If, after your change, you immediately test in another browser or incognito, you also see the column in a minimum width.


In list:

Result in web part:

As you see, Column1 is much smaller in the web part. Even on full screen.
How can we change the column width loaded via a web part?

This should be achieved through CSS. First install Script Editor, and then try the appropriate code such as:
<style type='text/css'>
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='<ColumnName>']
{
  width:250px;
}
</style>

Reference:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42760/increase-column-width-in-a-list-view-web-part

Thank you but your solution is for SharePoint 2016 or older. SharePoint Online  works in a different way. If it's possible to edit the width in an old view, why isn't it possible in the new view?
